# selenium right click on javascript page

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to do a right click with actionChains. Until now, I've done this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
actions = ActionChains(driver)

action.context_click("id=project-root").perform
```

the `id=project-root` is where a normal left click would point to. If I execute this script, I get:

```
line 215, in <lambda>
self._driver.execute(Command.MOVE_TO, {'element': to_element.id}))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add `build` method before `perform` method.
It should be like this:

```
action.context_click("id=project-root").build.perform
```

I am not sure about python coding structure but in C# it is like:

```
var rightClick = new Actions(_driver);
rightClick.ContextClick(elementToRightCllick).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Tried that, python ActionChains class doesn't seem to have the build attribute.

Comment: Then it is something to do with element identification. Try using the following code: action.context_click(driver.findelement("id=project-root")).perform

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
WebElement onElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(CQLo.getLink_WFM_Admin()));
    act.contextClick(onElement).perform();
    act.sendKeys("o").perform();
```

this is an example that could help you understand, in this example you are going to open a link in a new window. I put sendkkey "o" because after clicking the rigth button you press the letter "o" to open a new window

regards